# Disable function after onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function that automatically loads when the pages opens. I want the function to stop running after "onclick". I want the slideshow to stop running automatically after clicking a button.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function changeImage(x){
             imageNumber += x;

             if(imageNumber > imageLength){
                 imageNumber = 0;
             }

             if(imageNumber < 0){
                 imageNumber = imageLength;
             }

             document.getElementById("slideshow").src = images[imageNumber];
             document.getElementById("caption").innerHTML = caption[imageNumber];

             return false;
         }

         function autoRun(){
            //This function simply makes the slideshow change slides every 5 seconds.
            setInterval("changeImage(1)", 5000);
         }

         function clearFunction(){
            //This function needs to stop the autoRun function. 
            //If the user wants to manual flip through the slides, 
            //I don't want the slides to continue changing automatically
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body onload="autoRun()">

      <a href="#" onclick="changeImage(-1); clearFunction();">Previous Slide</a>

      <a href="#" onclick="changeImage(1); clearFunction();">Next Slide</a>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can create a global variable. For example: var checkRun = true; You can check this variable in the function and set it to false in the first run.

Comment: Well the autoRun() must be doing setInterval of some kind. You need to maintain a reference to it outside autoRun() and use clearInterval in your clearFunction(). Please post the content of autoRun()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intervals can be cleared:

```
var interval;
function autoRun(){
        //This function simply makes the slideshow change slides every 5 seconds.
        interval=setInterval(changeImage, 5000,1);
}
function clearFunction(){
        if(interval) clearInterval(interval);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the code in `autoRun()` inside an `if(flag)` with `flag` being a boolean that is initially set to `true` and then you can set `flag=false` inside `clearFunction()`, so whenever `clearFunction()` is called, `flag` is set to `false` and the code inside `autorun()` won't execute because it won't pass the `if(flag)` check.

Note that `flag` needs to be a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a window **interval** that calls `autoRun` every 5000 milliseconds.

```
// anywhere in your script, outside of any function
let timer = window.setInterval(changeImage, 5000);
```

In the `clearFunction` function, just do

```
window.clearInterval(timer);
```

See [window.setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use clearInterval

```
var interval = 1;         
    function autoRun(){
                //This function simply makes the slideshow change slides every 5 seconds.
        interval = setInterval(changeImage, 5000, 1);
    }

    function clearFunction(){
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
```